# How do I send a post request to a website's server in python?

Tags: python, post, get

I want to send a post request instead of a GET request to google.com's server in python.

My code so far is:

```
import socket
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler



HOST = 'www.chase.com'
PORT = 80

socket = socket.socket()
socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
socket.send(b"""
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: chase.com

""")
msg = socket.recv(1024)
print(msg)
```

Can someone help me send a post request to google.com?

Comment: Why are you using low-level sockets?

Comment: @JohnGordon what's a low level socket

Comment: There are many modules that can do the http for you (like [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) in the stdlib). Would one of those be appropriate? You could search "post" in that link for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the requests module :

```py
import requests
data = {"what you want to post":"in form of dict"}
url = "your url"
response = requests.post(url, json=data)

print(response)
```

before, you have to run this command to install requests module :

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: What should I put for the variable data?

Comment: @YxngJay We can't answer that for you.  Send _what you want to send_.  We don't know what you want to send...

Comment: @JohnGordon can it be anything?

Comment: @YxngJay It just has to be in form of dictionnary

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help me send a post request to google.com?

This sounds like task for [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) (which is part of standard library), consider following simple example

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'x':1,'y':2,'z':3})
data = data.encode('ascii')
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/post", data) as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

gives output

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "x": "1", 
    "y": "2", 
    "z": "3"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Python-urllib/3.8", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-63efb182-4f75d5cd47cbe6916985ef10"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "213.134.180.174", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

I have used [`httpbin.org`](https://httpbin.org/) in my example as it is useful for debugging sending request, as it does respond with what it get. Observe that what you provide as `data` should be `bytes` so you need to `.encode` it and what you get as response is `bytes` so you need to `.decode` it if you want text (`str`).